# How to search users in groups and return display names using graph API?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Net core application. I have search box in web application where user can search user belongs to specific group. I am trying as below to search users

```
var members = await graphClient.Groups["0001b29c-fd90-4ae9-a5a1-h8afe65777e9"].Request().Expand("members").GetAsync();
var usersInGroup = members.Members.ToList();
```

In the above code I want to apply filter also to list users name starting with. I am struggling to apply filter. Can someone help me to add filters here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try below API to search users in groups

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/groupid/members/microsoft.graph.user?$count=true&$orderby=displayName&$search="displayName:sr"&$select=displayName,id

ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sruthi but same thing how can I write in c#?

Comment: Also how can I add starts with in the above request?

Comment: for `startswith` use this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/groupid/members/microsoft.graph.user?$count=true&$filter=startsWith(displayName,'sr')&$select=displayName,id`

Comment: I used it but its displaying all the rows but I want to search display name starts with specific name

Comment: I tried with above query and now getting error as "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.",

Comment: please add request header `ConsistencyLevel: eventual`

Comment: This worked like charm, Thanks a lot but I want to make it in .Net core. any idea how to write?

Comment: Hi Sruthi, Is it possible to check in multiple groups also possible?